# "radeon disabling gpu acceleration" hang on boot of clean CentOS 6.2 Minimal install

Tags: boot, freeze, centos, integrated-graphics

I have a clean install of CentOS 6.2 minimal on a server. On boot, just after the GRUB boot loader screen, I get a message that's about 3 lines long and very blurry. The same message appears on the screen in several places at once, and the server appears to hang at this point. The only words I can read are the last line, which reads:

`radeon 0000-01-05.0 disabling gpu acceleration`

This appears to be a graphics related problem. I'm using the basic on-board integrated graphics card.

Does anyone know if there's a grub argument that can work around the problem?

This is a server so it should just be a basic command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I'll answer anyway.

You want to hit "Install CentOS with Basic Video Driver" instead of the first option.